# How to fix ReferenceError jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cant find the error from my code,took me hours trying to figure it out but still cant make it work.

 I've checked on the browser console and it shows as ascreenshot  below :
[image]

 Here's my code :

```
<?php  
session_start();

use Phpml\Classification\SVC;
use Phpml\SupportVectorMachine\Kernel;

include "koneksi.php";
include "function.php";

if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header('location:login.php');
}else{
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Pelatihan SVM</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/2nd.css">
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<?php  
    cekUser();
?>
</head>
<body>
<div class="tab">
<button class="menuTab" onclick="switchMenu(event, 'useDatabase')" id="admin">Data Mentah</button>
<button class="menuTab" onclick="switchMenu(event, 'term')" id="nonAdmin">Data Feature Selection</button>
</div>

<div id="useDatabase" class="tabContent">
<?php  
    $start=0;
    $limit=100;

    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $id=$_GET['id'];
        $start=($id-1)*$limit;
    }else{
        $id=1;
    }

    $q = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM dataset_latih LIMIT $start, $limit")or die(mysqli_error($db));
    $no=$start+1;

    $q1=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT COUNT('label') AS 'label positif' FROM dataset_latih WHERE label='positif'");
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q1);
    $positif=$row['label positif'];

    $q2=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT COUNT('label') AS 'label negatif' FROM dataset_latih WHERE label='negatif'");
    $row2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q2);
    $negatif=$row2['label negatif'];
?>
<h2 align="center">Dataset Latih</h2>
<h3 style="text-align: center;">Positif : <?php echo $positif; ?> | Negatif : <?php echo $negatif; ?> | Total : <?php echo $positif+$negatif; ?></h3>


<table border=1 align="center" class="h-header">
    <thead>
        <tr> 
            <th width="25">No.</th>
            <th width="1200">Komentar</th>
            <th width="70">Kelas</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<?php
    while ( $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q) ) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $no . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='kiri'>" . $result['komentar'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $result['label'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $no++;
    }
?>
</table>    
<div class='wrapper'>
    <button class='button' id="prosesData">Proses</button>
</div>
<div class="paging" style="text-align: center;">
    <?php 
        $rows=mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM dataset_latih"));
        $total=ceil($rows/$limit);
        if ($id>1) {
            echo "<a href='?id=".($id-1)."' class='button' id='table1'>Previous </a>";
        }

        for ($i=1; $i <=$total ; $i++) { 
            if ($i==$id) {
                echo "<span class='active'>$i</span>";
            }else{
                echo "<a href='?id=".$i."' id='table1'> ".$i." </a>";
            }
        }

        if ($id!=$total) {
            echo "<a href='?id=".($id+1)."' class='button' id='table1'> Next</a>";
        }
    ?>
</div>
</div>

<div id="term" class="tabContent">
<h2 align="center">Term Latih</h2>
    <?php  
        $start=0;
        $limit=100;

        if(isset($_GET['id1'])){
            $id1=$_GET['id1'];
            $start=($id1-1)*$limit;
        }else{
            $id1=1;
        }

        $q = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM data_latih_ready LIMIT $start, $limit")or die(mysqli_error($db));
        $no=$start+1;

        $rowPersentase = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM selected_feature"))or die(mysqli_error($db));
        $persentase = $rowPersentase['persentase'];

        $td1 = '';
        $td2 = '';
        $td3 = '';
        while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
            $td1 .= "<td>$no</td>";
            $td2 .= "<td>".$row1['term']."</td>";
            $td3 .= "<td>".$row1['tf_idf_normalisasi']."</td>";
            $no++;
        }
    ?>
<h3 style="text-align: center;">Feature Selection : <?php echo $persentase; ?>%</h3>

<div class="v-header">
    <table border="1" align="center" cellpadding="20">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No.</th>
                <?php echo $td1; ?>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Term</th>
                <?php echo $td2; ?>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Normalisasi TF.IDF</th>
                <?php echo $td3; ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
<!-- <br> -->

<div class="paging2" style="text-align: center;">
    <?php 
        $rows=mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM data_latih_ready"));
        $total=ceil($rows/$limit);
        if ($id1>1) {
            echo "<a href='?id1=".($id1-1)."' class='button' id='table2'>Previous </a>";
        }

        for ($i=1; $i <=$total; $i++) { 
            if ($i==$id1) {
                echo "<span class='active'>$i</span>";
            }else{
                echo "<a href='?id1=".$i."' id='table2'> ".$i." </a>";
            }
        }

        if ($id1!=$total) {
            echo "<a href='?id1=".($id1+1)."' class='button' id='table2'> Next</a>";
        }
    ?>
    <div class="btnFeature">
        <ul>
        <li>
            <button class="button" onclick="train();">Latih SVM</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button class="button" id="featureSelection">Feature Selection</button>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="info" align="center">
<p>Tabel di atas merupakan tabel term dengan nilai yang telah disesuaikan dengan nilai <strong>Feature Selection</strong><br>
Silahkan menekan tombol <strong>Latih SVM</strong> jika <strong>Feature Selection</strong> sudah sesuai kebutuhan.
</p>
</div>

<?php  
$cek = cekTabelToken(); 
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
// biar otomatis tab aktif waktu halaman svmLatih.php dibuka
document.getElementById("admin").click();
$(".info").hide();

$("#admin").click(function(){
    $(".info").hide();
});

$("#nonAdmin").click(function(){
    $(".info").show();

}); 

// var untuk cek tabel term kosong gk
var cek = "<?php echo "$cek"; ?>"

$("#prosesData").click(function(){
    // kalau tabel term gk kosong, alert mau proses ulang gk
    if (cek > 0) {
        var conf = confirm("Preprocessing data latih sudah pernah dilakukan.\nIngin memproses ulang ?");
        if (conf == true) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "action.php",
                data:{action: "prosesUlangDataLatih"},
                type: "POST",
                // kalau berhasil kasih alert lalu redirect
                success: function(){
                    alert("Preprocessing ulang selesai.");
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        window.location.href = 'featureSelection.php';
                        },1000);
                    }
                });
            }
    }else{
        // kalau tabel term kosong ya langsung aja proses
        $.ajax({
            url: "action.php",
            data:{action: "preprocessing"},
            type: "POST",
            // kalau berhasil kasih alert lalu redirect
            success: function(){
                alert("Preprocessing selesai.");
                setTimeout(function(){
                    window.location.href = 'featureSelection.php';
                },1000);
            }
        });
    }
});

// fungsi untuk switch tab
function switchMenu(evt, selectedMenu){
    var i, tabContent, menuTab;
    tabContent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabContent");

    for (i = 0; i < tabContent.length; i++) {
        tabContent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    menuTab = document.getElementsByClassName("menuTab");
    for(i = 0; i < menuTab.length; i++){
        menuTab[i].className = menuTab[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }       

    document.getElementById(selectedMenu).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// tombol feature selection
$("#featureSelection").click(function(){
    window.location = "featureSelection.php";
});

// tombol latih SVM
function train(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "action.php",
        data:{
            action: "trainDatabase"
        },
        success: function(){
            alert("Model SVM sudah dibuat.");
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope someone can help me to find the error, I've been stuck here for hours. Thank you.

Comment: why you get event in `switchMenu` ?

Comment: Any errors when the page loads? If there's a syntax error in your script, it will fail and the `switchMenu` function will not be created.

Comment: @squint there's no error when the page loads

Comment: What if you comment out this line: `document.getElementById("admin").click();`

Comment: still the same error my friend.

Comment: I can't see what's wrong. It may help to post the actual rendered page instead of the PHP.

Comment: Actually that's the rendered page.

Comment: With all the `<?php` stuff?

Comment: yes, does it make the error comes out ?

Comment: I use the `<?php ?>` because I need to fetch data form mySQL

Comment: That's server-side code. I meant to show the page as it arrives in the browser. Not sure if it'll help though. I don't see any issue with what you provided.

Comment: Oh. So you want me to screenshot the page ?

Comment: No, you can view the source of the page if you find the `View Source` menu, or something like it. Or you can use the `Inspector` tab of the development tools.

Comment: hey, what's the difference of putting `<script></script>` on `<head>` and `<body>` ?

Comment: Works both ways, but if it's in the `<head>` it will run before the elements below it have a chance to load. You seem to have it low enough that the elements will exist when it runs.

Comment: I think I should change my code. Thank you mate.